# Why do identical folders on two different hard drives of the same file count and file sizes, take up a different size on disk?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, disk-space

Both have

- 216,540 files
- 52,103 folders
- Size: 278 GB (299,363,715,785 bytes)

But for one hard drive the size on disk is 278 GB (299,672,**182,784** bytes)  and for another it's 278 GB (299,672,**211,456** bytes) bytes).

That's a difference of 28,672 bytes or 28.67KB.

Why?

Comment: How are these *"identical folders on two different hard drives"* created (e.g. is one a copy of the other)?  Are the two drives & filesystems otherwise identical (e.g. same filesystem parameters)?

Comment: What method did you use to confirm the 2 folders are identical?  Maybe a couple hidden files weren't copied.  Maybe one of the 216,540 files was truncated?

Comment: I opened the folder's properties. File Explorer told me so. I have also synchronised both folders with DSynchronize. The file system on both external hard drives are NTFS. http://dimio.altervista.org/eng/#DSynchronize